# Instagram access token broke and needed a new one?

Tags: javascript, token, instagram

So I embed a website to have a instagram feed using this website: http://instafeedjs.com/

I got it working and it was up for a week or so and it randomly broke one day with an error "Invalid access Token".

I got a new token and it works again but I'm curious as to why my original Token needed a refresh? They aren't supposed to expire from what I hear. Anyone have any thoughts on this, so I can find out why it broke?

Comment: Sounds more like a question for Instagram's developer support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instagram doesn't provide an expiration time for their tokens, which can expire at any time.

The following text is from [Instagram's Developer Authentication page](https://instagram.com/developer/authentication/):

> Access tokens may expire at any time in the future. [...]
>
> Even though the access token does not specify an expiration time, your app should handle the case that either the user revokes access, or Instagram expires the token after some period of time. In this case, your meta of your responses will contain an “error_type=OAuthAccessTokenError”. In other words: do not assume your access_token is valid forever.